# What is the correct place for Nuget Change Log specification?

Tags: nuget, .net-4.5, dependency-management, nuspec, proget

I am publishinga Nuget package in incrementally iterative and highly-frequent mode.

What is the best place to put the change-log? Is it the [Description].

Or is there a specific place to put the change-log in a reverse chronological order?

I would eventually push this package to [ProGet] too...and if there is any practice around it regarding change-log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this value in the `<releaseNotes>` element (from the [NuGet .nuspec reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference)):

> A description of the changes made in each release of the package. This
>   field only shows up when the *Updates* tab is selected and the package
>   is an update to a previously installed package. It is displayed where
>   the Description would normally be displayed.

Since this is interpreted by the NuGet client and not the server, the ProGet handling is the same.

Comment: Worth noting that, at least as of Visual Studio 2022 v17.5.3 the `releaseNotes` element is still **not** displayed in the Visual Studio package manager UI, either for package install or update.